# How to convert a .c or a .o or a .exe file to a .obj file?

Tags: c, lc3, object-files

I am building an LC3 Virtual Machine in C, but one problem that I am facing is that it takes in only .obj files as input. How am I to convert any file that I write in C into a .obj file in order to run it through the Virtual Machine

Comment: Hi, what compiler are you using ? Also, what do you understand of the compilation / building process (do you know what an `obj` file is) ?

Comment: As long as the format is correct, you can simply rename a.o to a.obj, if we look only at the extensions. But as you say you want to run a program, you might need to rename the executable file. However, a.exe might not be the correct format. Make sure you understand the building process.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of lc3 that you should write the assembly by hand? I guess you could read this though: [compiling C for LC3](https://www.cemgokmen.com/programming/2018-10-10-compiling-C-for-LC3/)

Comment: What is an .obj file?

Comment: when you said "building a virtual machine" does that mean you are writing it, or someone else wrote it and you are compiling it?

Comment: In order to run a C program on a machine (any machine), you need a C compiler that targets that machine. Do you have a C compiler that targets LC3? You probably can find one if you search hard enough. In order to run a binary program on a different kind of machine (e.g. run an .exe from your Windows machine on an LC3), you need a binary-to-binary translator or an emulator. I doubt you can find one that target LC3.

Comment: `.o` and `.obj` are both common file extensions for object files, and both occur in a wide variety of forms (different formats, different target CPUs). What you need is not just `.obj` files. You need `.obj` files that are built for the LC3 architecture. You need a C compiler that generates LC3 object code from C source code. (Any existing `.o` or `.exe` files you have will not be useful.)